# I'm trying to download an APK by clicking a link with new tab, but the tab closes immediately after it opens in Chrome Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, download, apk

**Issue present only with downloading APK**

It works fine on all desktop browsers and android Fire Fox as well. Problem is only with Android Chrome (works fine in Samsung mobiles chrome).

*Note: I am having the Valid HTTPS certificate.*

Code Snippet:
window.open('**https://awsBucket**/app.apk', '_blank');